# Do all 3 channels of HSB / HSV require the same precision?

Tags: colors

In RGB, all 3 channels are usually 8 bit, meaning they are all equally "precise".

If I wanted to store HSB / HSV also in 24 bits (for color manipulations / art creation, rather then rendering), are all channels also equally important, or doesn't it make more sense to give more precision to H? Say 10/7/7 bits instead of 8/8/8 bits? Or maybe 9/8/7, or 9/7/8 bits?

Alternatively, I could use 32 bits, but I can't really afford to use one float per channel, as is usual in HSB. And 32 cannot be divided by 3, so I still need different channel bit depths.

Put another way, which combination of bit-depth per channel maps to the greatest number of RGB colors, since that is what it has to get mapped to when it gets rendered?

Comment: Can you be more clear about why you can't afford to use 4 bytes per channel ? You can certainly use 8 bits per channel in the conversion from RGB to HSV, but you will lose data that might be useful if you want to convert back to RGB. At http://code.google.com/p/streumix-frei0r-goodies/wiki/Integer_based_RGB_HSV_conversion you will find an implementation that says by using 12 bits it is able to keep all the needed information for the conversion.

Comment: @mmgp I intend to use this to store 3D voxel data; millions of voxels in a Java applet. Going from 8 to 32 would quadruple the amount of required RAM, which translates to reducing the amount of voxel by 4, and increasing the processing time for the same amount of voxels (the more memory you access, the longer it takes). But assuming that website is correct, I would have accepted your comment as an answer, since it tells me all I need to know, to make the best decision. :)